# push notifications for uwp without phonegap or azure with cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, uwp

I am developing an application for windows 10, android and IOS. I am currently implementing notifications for these 3 platforms and I successfully installed FCM for Android (IOs waiting for testing). Since FCM doesn't work with windows, I am trying to implement push notifications for uwp (not windows 8 or 8.1, but windows 10). All I can find in documentation is about microsoft azure or phonegap, but I don't want to use Azure because I already paid for a developer account in microsoft and I don't want to pay again for azure (same with phonegap, I don't want to pay). All I could find is this page

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-ca/windows/uwp/monetize/configure-your-app-to-receive-dev-center-notifications

But the code in the documentation is in C# and I am using javascript (my application is in ionic 2).

**TL;DR**

Is there a way to implement push notification for UWP with cordova, without using neither phonegap neither azure ?

Comment: Azure is not a must for push notification. Please refer to [Windows Push Notification Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview).

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT but in order to authenticate those WNS messages you need to use the developer portal in azure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh868206(v%3dwin.10) right?